# Is there anyway to Develop Android on VM

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am having a lot of issue about it.

I gotta say that "My computer has 4 gb ram, so I'cant running Android studio effectively.

Firstly, I created an Google Virtual Machine(has 8 gb ram) and I downloaded android studio. But emulator didn't worked.
Then I started to researching about this issue, in my opinion I need to enable nested virtualization on VM. I followed those steps "https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances" but it didn't worked. Genymotion, Bluestacks and many android emulator didn't worked.

How can I develop Android Apps on Virtual Machines?
If is there anyway for it, please let me know.

Comment: Although the linked question was about a windows cloud instance, the answer there discusses Linux instances as well.  Beyond being a duplicate, this question is really too broad for Stackoverflow as well.  Also worth considering that you don't really need an emulator if you have a physical device to debug on.  And yes, there are ways to tunnel ADB to or from the cloud, for example with SSH port forwards.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you are looking for a Desktop-as-a-Service (DaaS) or a Virtual Cloud Desktop. With DaaS, desktop operating systems run inside virtual machines on servers in a cloud provider's data center.

In fact, you can use a virtual machine like Google Engine but you will need to configure everything to your needs,but and the VM may not support everything. DaaS should be easier to setup compared to Google Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need a VPS with GPU support.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you will need to enable nested virtualization on GCP VM as reference [1](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#accel-vm).

To the development environment requirements, your computer's processor must support one of the following virtualization extensions technologies:

Intel Virtualization Technology (VT, VT-x, vmx) extensions

AMD Virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) extensions

Now, could you please check that you are following below 4 recommendations as [2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances#troubleshooting):

-- Use one of the “ tested operating systems” on the Compute Engine instance that hosts your nested VMs

-- Use the standard procedure for “starting a nested VM”

-- Make sure you have started your VM with a “CPU platform of Haswell or higher”

-- Make sure you are “using the correct license” with your VM image

If you are following the above listed  recommendations,could you please share what error message you are getting?